# How to access aNotification.userInfo dictionary on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, push-notification

I am trying to obtain the alert message details when my app is opened when the user clicks on the Notification Alert message on his MAC.

I have no problem getting the Alert when the app is opened. The following delegate works fine for when the App is already opened.

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication,
                          didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : Any])
```

However when the App is opened via the clicking od the Alert Notification I have to get the userInfo from

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
```

I am unable to retrieve the alert `userInfo` in this function.

```
let mydictionary = aNotification.userInfo
let mydesc = mydictionary!.description
os_log("aNotification.userInfon= %{public}@", log: osLog, mydesc)
```

The output from `os_log`, I can see the alert message in the description.

> `aNotification.userInfon= [AnyHashable("NSApplicationLaunchIsDefaultLaunchKey"): 0, AnyHashable("NSApplicationLaunchUserNotificationKey"): <UNNotificationResponse: 0x600003ac1480; actionIdentifier: com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier, notification: <UNNotification: 0x600003ac1580; date: 2019-05-08 18:26:59 +0000, request: <UNNotificationRequest: 0x6000034cd560; identifier: E6D76BF3-6643-4627-BF38-3B11B5C3F0B3, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x600000fe0780; title: (null), subtitle: (null), body: (14) - iPhone - Tom Owen, summaryArgument: , summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
>   ), badge: 0, sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x600001ee92c0>,, trigger: <UNPushNotificationTrigger: 0x6000038fa780; contentAvailable: NO, mutableContent: NO>>>>]`

I have tried many ways to access the "dictionary", the following is one way.

```
if let aps = aNotification.userInfo!["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        os_log(" aNotification.userInfo ok", log: osLog)
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
            os_log("alert ok", log: osLog)
            if let alertMessage = alert["body"] as? String {
                os_log("body ok", log: osLog)
                message = alertMessage
            }
        }
    } else {
        os_log("no aNotification.userInfo!", log: osLog)
    }
```

However I keep getting "no aNotification.userInfo!"

How should I be accessing "body: (14) - iPhone - Tom Owen" from `userInfo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a closer look at the log. You have to get the user notification with the key `launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey`. The value for that key is an `UNNotificationResponse` instance.

You get the `body` with

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification)
    if let response = notification.userInfo?[NSApplication.launchUserNotificationUserInfoKey] as? UNNotificationResponse {
       let content = response.notification.request.content
       let body = content.body
       message = body
    }
}
```

However `didReceiveRemoteNotification` passes the traditional `userInfo` dictionary

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [String : Any]) {
    if let aps = userInfo?["aps"] as? [String:Any] { // please use Swift native types
        os_log(" aNotification.userInfo ok", log: osLog)
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String:Any] {
            os_log("alert ok", log: osLog)
            if let alertMessage = alert["body"] as? String {
                os_log("body ok", log: osLog)
                message = alertMessage
            }
        }
    } else {
        os_log("no aNotification.userInfo!", log: osLog)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just got your message. That did it, Working like a charm. You are the best!